# Flutter how to deploy updates without updating on the play store?'

Tags: flutter, dart

So in some apps, I noticed that there is a new button, feature etc without me updating on the play store how can I do it on an app developed using flutter

Comment: Depends on the feature you want to implement. What have you tried?

Comment: Some of that is just server side, the app was pre-programmed to do it. you can't update a package without installing it in some form, That's how things work in android afaik

Comment: If you haven’t disabled it, apps usually get updated automatically, e.g. over night or so.

Comment: @daddygames I wanted to just add a button like when the participants finish the challenge a new button should pop but after 30 days of challenges

Comment: You may build your app with that business logic in mind. Flutter allows you to dynamically create the components displayed to the user based on your own business logic. This doesn't necessitate a "patch" of some kind to the app. Instead, your app should be aware that this change could be triggered and account for it in code. It's not really clear why you want to "patch" the app or what you have available in the existing, deployed app that could allow you to add a button and make it do something.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want something like **expo OTA update**, that is currently neither possible, nor on the roadmap, [accourding to Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14330#issuecomment-485565194). :(

Answer (score 0):

You can pull information from a database that will update your app, so basically for example

```
var backgroundColor = firebaseColor
```

firebaseColor can be edited in firebase(or another backend), so whenever you set it in firebase it will update in the app and change the appearance of the app without actually pushing an update. this is an over simplistic explanation but the concept works with anything.

Comment: so just tap into the database? I had an idea what if I use the sleep module and after the x amount of time put the new button or anything will it still work? I'm a noob please excuse me if this is a dumb solution